# What do these Two Lines in Mod_Rewrite do?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've benn trying to figure out what these two lines in Mod_Rewrite do and would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They check if the requested URI is an existing file or a directory. The `!` in front makes the condition "not", thus,, the request does NOT map to a file or directory.

See the [`-f` and `-d` description in mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

---

> Don't all requests map to some file so that it can be loaded by the browser?

No. The request could be for something that doesn't exist and be rewritten. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/something would mean the URI is `/wiki/something`, which doesn't map to any physical file or directory. But internally, there is a rule that rewrites `/wiki/something` to `index.php?title=something`, and `index.php` **does** exist.

---

Edit: for edited question

- The 2 conditions: if the requested URI doesn't map to a file or a directory, apply the following rule.
- The rule: Take whatever the request is, and append a `.php` to the end.
- The logic behind this: mod_rewrite loops until the URI that goes into the rewrite engine and the URI that comes out of it is identical. Without the check to see if the URI maps to a physical file or directory, the rule will loop:

  - URI in = /something
  - Check conditions: /something doesn't exist
  - Apply rule, URI in = /something.php
  - Check conditions: /something.php EXISTS, don't apply rule
  - URI in = URI out = /something.php, stop rewriting
- Otherwise, without the `!-f` and `!-d` checks:

  - URI in = /something
  - Apply rule, URI = /something.php
  - URI in = /something.php
  - Apply rule, URI = /something.php.php
  - URI in = /something.php.php
  - Apply rule, URI = /something.php.php.php
  - loop indefinitely until apache decides to stop and return a 500 error

Comment: Don't all requests map to some file so that it can be loaded by the browser?

Comment: @user532493 Requests for static files don't need to be re-written, so you'll often find those two conditions before the main rewrite rule for a site

Comment: Why is the URI with the .php added sent back into the mod_rewrite engine at all? Why doesn't the mod_rewrite engine just add the .php once after going through all 3 lines and stop?

Comment: @user532493 because mod_rewrite loops until the URI going into the engine is the same as the one leaving the engine. That's just the way it works. Note that this happens even with the `[L]` flag.

Comment: The `[R]` or `[P]` flags will cause rewriting to stop, since it sends it off either as a redirect or an internal proxy. It could be that the redirect or proxy ends up going back through the rewrite engine later.