# RerwiteRule for migrating website code staying on the same Domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I am trying to do is add another RewriteRule to this configuration so that old URLs like these will be redirected to the root of the site

```
http://www.acme.com/category.php?id=6
http://www.acme.com/product.php?id=183&category=
```

I know that "category.php" and "product.php" will now be a invalid strings. Using "category.php" as an example I tried altering the config to be this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category.php(.*) / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will redirect as follows

```
http://www.acme.com/category.php?id=112 -> http://www.acme.com/?id=112
```

I have two problems

1. I don't want the query string to be appended. I haven't specified
   [QSA]
2. If I enter the root directly `www.acme.com` the page won't display
   unless I remove the line I just added. Why would my new RewriteRule
   affect URL's that dont start with "category.php"?

**[Edit]**

I have also tried this instead of the redirect above, but I still seem to be getting both rules being applied

```
RewriteRule ^category.php /holdingPage.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the 2 conditions to be tied to the old rule that sends everything through `index.php` and you need to add your new rule *above* them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category.php /? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To deal with **1.**, I've added a "**?**" at the end of the / in the rule's target. That makes it so query strings won't automatically get appended unless you specifically have the `QSA` flag. As for **2.**, not sure why it wasn't working for you, but it may have had something to do with the 2 conditions that were being applied to the wrong rule.

---

EDIT:

For a description of the 2 `RewriteCond` lines, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275339/851273

A `RewriteCond` is essentially a conditional, this block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

is essentially this (in pseudo code):

```
if(request_uri != maps_to_existing file) {
    if(request_uri != maps_to_existing_directory) {
        request_uri = request_uri.replace("([^?]*)", "index.php?_route_=$1", "[L,QSA]");
    }
}
```

The thing is, a `RewriteCond`, or many of them one directly after another, only applies to the immediately following `RewriteRule`, so without moving the category.php rule out in front, the pseudoc deo equivalent would have been:

```
if(request_uri != maps_to_existing file) {
    if(request_uri != maps_to_existing_directory) {
        request_uri = request_uri.replace("^category.php", "/?", "[L,R=301]");
    }
}
request_uri = request_uri.replace("([^?]*)", "index.php?_route_=$1", "[L,QSA]");
```

Which is kind of broken because the 2 `if()` conditionals are being mis-applied. Specifically the one that rewrites to "index.php" sort of requires the conditionals in order to prevent itself from looping.

Comment: Thank you Jon, that does the trick. However, are you able to explain (or point me to some docs) why moving the RewriteRule above the RewriteCond behaves differently? I assumed the RewriteCond's were just matching on requests for "files" and "directories"

Comment: Thank you Jon. I appreciate you taking the time to explain.